# What did time move on from?

Tags: bill-watterson, john-kascht, the-mysteries

*The Mysteries* contains the following:

> Rather late,
> the people grew alarmed.
> Time moved on.

I'm somewhat confused about what this means, though - what did it move on from?

Comment: Not knowing the work, I assume it means simply 'Time passed'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Time moved on’ is a standard English construction meaning ‘time passed’.

[Ludwig.guru.com](https://ludwig.guru/s/as+time+moved) gives sourced examples of the usage from several British and American websites.

> It has become less unusual as time moved on and women enter supposedly male jobs," she says. [the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/jun/04/battle-brewing-female-beermakers-take-aim-at-industry-sexism#:%7E:text=It%20has%20become%20less%20unusual%20as%20time%20moved%20on%20and%20women%20enter%20supposedly%20male%20jobs%2C%22%20she%20says.%20)

> As time moved on, though, my questions about the Kennedy assassination gave in to a general acceptance that Oswald had acted alone. [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/18/opinion/sunday/no-stranger-to-conspiracy.html#:%7E:text=As%20time%20moved%20on%2C%20though%2C%20my%20questions%20about%20the%20Kennedy%20assassination%20gave%20in%20to%20a%20general%20acceptance%20that%20Oswald%20had%20acted%20alone.%20)(pay-walled link)